# How to disable arrow keys in console in C

Tags: c

I'm using the termios.h header file to implement a console in RAW mode and I'm trying to disable
the arrow keys. I'm currently using the ctype.h file to test if the char I get from console is alphanumerical, however the up arrow is sent as the letter A.

How do I disable the arrow keys.

Thanks

Comment: Up-arrow should appear as A with a modifier/escape sequence.  You need to check for that with whatever interface you have.

Comment: the escape seq is ^A but as I'm getting a char at a time I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There were probably characters ahead of the `A` that were thrown out. You need to figure out what those characters were. The following code will help you figure out the sequence of characters that each arrow key generates.  Once you know that, you can modify the code to ignore those sequences.

```
int main( void )
{
    int c;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
        printf( "%02x\n", c );
}
```

Comment: Indeed, and the answer is: 0x1b (ASCII ESC), 0x5b ('['), 0x41 ('A').  So if you want to disable this, when you see 0x1b, check for '[' next, and if so, eat those plus one more character.

Answer (score 0):

What you think to use libreadline?

I use this library in a project where i build a console, and works so good. You can see the documentation here: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html